# How to edit a .bst file to get bold volume number in case of articles?

Tags: bibtex, custom-bib

I have the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{mybst}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

My `.bib` file is

```
@article{liberti2009,
 title={Reformulations in mathematical programming: Definitions and systematics},
 author={Liberti, Leo},
journal={RAIRO-Operations Research},
volume={43},
number={01},
pages={55--85},
year={2009},
publisher={Cambridge Univ Press}
}
```

I have successfully edited some parts of the `mybst.bst` file...

```
% ====================== mybst.BST ================ % 

ENTRY
  { address
    author
    booktitle
    chapter
    edition
    editor
    howpublished
    institution
    journal
    key
    month
    note
    number
    organization
    pages
    publisher
    school
    series
    title
    type
    volume
    year
  }
  {}
  { label }

INTEGERS { output.state before.all mid.sentence after.block }

FUNCTION {init.state.consts}
{ #0 'before.all :=
  #1 'mid.sentence :=
  #2 'after.block :=
}

STRINGS { s t }

FUNCTION {output.nonnull}
{ 's :=
  output.state mid.sentence =
    { ", " * write$ }
    { output.state after.block =
    { add.period$ write$
      newline$
      "\newblock " write$
    }
    'write$
      if$
      mid.sentence 'output.state :=
    }
  if$
  s
}

FUNCTION {output}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    'pop$
    'output.nonnull
  if$
}

FUNCTION {output.check}
{ 't :=
  duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "empty " t * " in " * cite$ * warning$ }
    'output.nonnull
  if$
}

FUNCTION {output.bibitem}
{ newline$
  "\bibitem{" write$
  cite$ write$
  "}" write$
  newline$
  ""
  before.all 'output.state :=
}

FUNCTION {fin.entry}
{ add.period$
  write$
  newline$
}

FUNCTION {new.block}
{ output.state before.all =
    'skip$
    { after.block 'output.state := }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {not}
{   { #0 }
    { #1 }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {and}
{   'skip$
    { pop$ #0 }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {or}
{   { pop$ #1 }
    'skip$
  if$
}

FUNCTION {new.block.checka}
{ empty$
    'skip$
    'new.block
  if$
}

FUNCTION {field.or.null}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    'skip$
  if$
}

FUNCTION {emphasize}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    { "{\em " swap$ * "}" * }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {scapify}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    { "{\sc " swap$ * "}" * }
  if$
}

INTEGERS { nameptr namesleft numnames }

FUNCTION {format.names}
{ 's :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
%    { s nameptr "{f.~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}" format.name$ 't :=
    { s nameptr "{f.~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}" format.name$ 't :=
      nameptr #1 >
    { namesleft #1 >
        { ", " * t * }
        { numnames #2 >
        { "," * }
        'skip$
          if$
          t "others" =
        { " et~al." * }
        { " and " * t * }
          if$
        }
      if$
    }
    't
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
}

STRINGS { last.authors }

FUNCTION {init.last.authors}
{ "" 'last.authors :=
}

FUNCTION {format.authors}
{ author empty$
    { "" 'last.authors :=
      ""
    }
    { author last.authors =
        { "\leavevmode\vrule height 2pt depth -1.6pt width 23pt" }
        { author format.names }  %author format.names scapify %% that small-capifies the lower case letters
      if$
      author 'last.authors :=
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.organization}
{ organization empty$
    { "" 'last.authors :=
      ""
    }
    { organization last.authors =
        { "\leavevmode\vrule height 2pt depth -1.6pt width 23pt" }
        { organization  }                    %scapify
      if$
      organization 'last.authors :=
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.editors}
{ editor empty$
    { "" 'last.authors :=
      ""
    }
    { editor last.authors =
        { "\leavevmode\vrule height 2pt depth -1.6pt width 23pt" }
    { editor format.names } %editor format.names scapify
      if$
      editor num.names$ #1 >
        { ", eds." * }
    { ", ed." * }
      if$
      editor 'last.authors :=
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.ineditors}
{ editor empty$
    { "" }
    { editor format.names
      editor num.names$ #1 >
    { ", eds." * }
    { ", ed." * }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.title}
{ title empty$
    { "" }
    { title "t" change.case$  } %emphasize
  if$
}

FUNCTION {n.dashify}
{ 't :=
  ""
    { t empty$ not }
    { t #1 #1 substring$ "-" =
    { t #1 #2 substring$ "--" = not
        { "--" *
          t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
        }
        {   { t #1 #1 substring$ "-" = }
        { "-" *
          t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
        }
          while$
        }
      if$
    }
    { t #1 #1 substring$ *
      t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
    }
      if$
    }
  while$
}

FUNCTION {format.date}
{ year empty$
    { month empty$
    { "" }
    { "there's a month but no year in " cite$ * warning$
      month
    }
      if$
    }
    { month empty$
    'year
    { month " " * year * }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.btitle}
{ title                                       %emphasize
}

FUNCTION {tie.or.space.connect}
{ duplicate$ text.length$ #3 <
    { "~" }
    { " " }
  if$
  swap$ * *
}

FUNCTION {either.or.check}
{ empty$
    'pop$
    { "can't use both " swap$ * " fields in " * cite$ * warning$ }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.bvolume}
{ volume empty$
    { "" }
    { "vol.~" volume *
      series empty$
    'skip$
    { " of " * series * }
      if$
      "volume and number" number either.or.check
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.number.series}
{ volume empty$
    { number empty$
    { series field.or.null }
    { "no.~" number *
      series empty$
        { "there's a number but no series in " cite$ * warning$ }
        { " in " * series * }
      if$
    }
      if$
    }
    { "" }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.edition}
{ edition empty$
    { "" }
    { edition "l" change.case$ "~ed." * }
  if$
}

INTEGERS { multiresult }

FUNCTION {multi.page.check}
{ 't :=
  #0 'multiresult :=
    { multiresult not
      t empty$ not
      and
    }
    { t #1 #1 substring$
      duplicate$ "-" =
      swap$ duplicate$ "," =
      swap$ "+" =
      or or
    { #1 'multiresult := }
    { t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't := }
      if$
    }
  while$
  multiresult
}

FUNCTION {format.pages}
{ pages empty$
    { "" }
    { pages multi.page.check
    { "~" pages n.dashify * } %pp.~
    { "p.~" pages * }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.vol.year}
{ volume field.or.null
  year empty$
    { "empty year in " cite$ * warning$ }
    { " (" year * ")" * * }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.chapter.pages}
{ chapter empty$
    'format.pages
    { type empty$
    { "ch.~" chapter * }
    { type "l" change.case$ chapter tie.or.space.connect }
      if$
      pages empty$
    'skip$
    { " " * format.pages * }  % ", "
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.in.ed.booktitle}
{ booktitle empty$
    { "" }
    { editor empty$
    { "in " booktitle * }
    { "in " booktitle * ", " * format.ineditors * }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {empty.misc.check}
{ author empty$ title empty$ howpublished empty$
  month empty$ year empty$ note empty$
  and and and and and
  key empty$ not and
    { "all relevant fields are empty in " cite$ * warning$ }
    'skip$
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.thesis.type}
{ type empty$
    'skip$
    { pop$
      type "l" change.case$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.tr.number}
{ type empty$
    { "Tech. Report" }
    'type
  if$
  number empty$
    { "l" change.case$ }
    { number tie.or.space.connect }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.article.crossref}
{ key empty$
    { journal empty$
    { "need key or journal for " cite$ * " to crossref " * crossref *
      warning$
      ""
    }
    { "in " journal * }
      if$
    }
    { "in " key * }
  if$
  " \cite{" * crossref * "}" *
}

FUNCTION {format.crossref.editor}
{ editor #1 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$
  editor num.names$ duplicate$
  #2 >
    { pop$ " et~al." * }
    { #2 <
    'skip$
    { editor #2 "{ff }{vv }{ll}{ jj}" format.name$ "others" =
        { " et~al." * }
        { " and " * editor #2 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$ * }
      if$
    }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.book.crossref}
{ volume empty$
    { "empty volume in " cite$ * "'s crossref of " * crossref * warning$
      "in "
    }
    { "vol.~" volume *
      " of " *
    }
  if$
  editor empty$
  editor field.or.null author field.or.null =
  or
    { key empty$
    { series empty$
        { "need editor, key, or series for " cite$ * " to crossref " *
          crossref * warning$
          "" *
        }
        { series * }
      if$
    }
    { key * }
      if$
    }
    { format.crossref.editor * }
  if$
  " \cite{" * crossref * "}" *
}

FUNCTION {format.incoll.inproc.crossref}
{ editor empty$
  editor field.or.null author field.or.null =
  or
    { key empty$
    { booktitle empty$
        { "need editor, key, or booktitle for " cite$ * " to crossref " *
          crossref * warning$
          ""
        }
        { "in " booktitle * }
      if$
    }
    { "in " key * }
      if$
    }
    { "in " format.crossref.editor * }
  if$
  " \cite{" * crossref * "}" *
}

FUNCTION {article}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  format.title "title" output.check
  crossref missing$
    { journal "journal" output.check
      format.vol.year output
    }
    { format.article.crossref output.nonnull }
  if$
  format.pages output
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {book}
{ output.bibitem
  author empty$
    { format.editors "author and editor" output.check }
    { format.authors output.nonnull
      crossref missing$
    { "author and editor" editor either.or.check }
    'skip$
      if$
    }
  if$
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  crossref missing$
    { format.bvolume output
      format.number.series output
      publisher "publisher" output.check
      address output
    }
    { format.book.crossref output.nonnull }
  if$
  format.edition output
  format.date "year" output.check
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {booklet}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors output
  format.title "title" output.check
  howpublished new.block.checka
  howpublished output
  address output
  format.date output
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {inbook}
{ output.bibitem
  author empty$
    { format.editors "author and editor" output.check }
    { format.authors output.nonnull
      crossref missing$
    { "author and editor" editor either.or.check }
    'skip$
      if$
    }
  if$
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  crossref missing$
    { format.bvolume output
      format.number.series output
      publisher "publisher" output.check
      address output
    }
    { format.book.crossref output.nonnull }
  if$
  format.edition output
  format.date "year" output.check
  format.chapter.pages "chapter and pages" output.check
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {incollection}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  format.title "title" output.check
  crossref missing$
    { format.in.ed.booktitle "booktitle" output.check
      format.bvolume output
      format.number.series output
      publisher "publisher" output.check
      address output
      format.edition output
      format.date "year" output.check
    }
    { format.incoll.inproc.crossref output.nonnull }
  if$
  format.chapter.pages output
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {inproceedings}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  format.title "title" output.check
  crossref missing$
    { format.in.ed.booktitle "booktitle" output.check
      format.bvolume output
      format.number.series output
      address empty$
    { organization output
      publisher output
      format.date "year" output.check
    }
    { address output.nonnull
      format.date "year" output.check
      organization output
      publisher output
    }
      if$
    }
    { format.incoll.inproc.crossref output.nonnull }
  if$
  format.pages output
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {conference} { inproceedings }

FUNCTION {manual}
{ output.bibitem
  author empty$
    { format.organization output }
    { format.authors output.nonnull }
  if$
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  author empty$
    'skip$
    { organization output }
  if$
  address output
  format.edition output
  format.date output
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {mastersthesis}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  format.title "title" output.check
  "master's thesis" format.thesis.type output.nonnull
  school "school" output.check
  address output
  format.date "year" output.check
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {misc}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors output
  format.title output
  howpublished new.block.checka
  howpublished output
  format.date output
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
  empty.misc.check
}

FUNCTION {phdthesis}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  "PhD thesis" format.thesis.type output.nonnull
  school "school" output.check
  address output
  format.date "year" output.check
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {proceedings}
{ output.bibitem
  editor empty$
    { format.organization output }
    { format.editors output.nonnull }
  if$
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  format.bvolume output
  format.number.series output
  address empty$
    { editor empty$
    'skip$
    { organization output }
      if$
      publisher output
      format.date "year" output.check
    }
    { address output.nonnull
      format.date "year" output.check
      editor empty$
    'skip$
    { organization output }
      if$
      publisher output
    }
  if$
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {techreport}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  format.title "title" output.check
  format.tr.number output.nonnull
  institution "institution" output.check
  address output
  format.date "year" output.check
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {unpublished}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  note "note" output.check
  format.date output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {default.type} { misc }

MACRO {jan} {"Jan."}

MACRO {feb} {"Feb."}

MACRO {mar} {"Mar."}

MACRO {apr} {"Apr."}

MACRO {may} {"May"}

MACRO {jun} {"June"}

MACRO {jul} {"July"}

MACRO {aug} {"Aug."}

MACRO {sep} {"Sept."}

MACRO {oct} {"Oct."}

MACRO {nov} {"Nov."}

MACRO {dec} {"Dec."}

READ

FUNCTION {sortify}
{ purify$
  "l" change.case$
}

INTEGERS { len }

FUNCTION {chop.word}
{ 's :=
  'len :=
  s #1 len substring$ =
    { s len #1 + global.max$ substring$ }
    's
  if$
}

FUNCTION {sort.format.names}
{ 's :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  ""
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { nameptr #1 >
    { "   " * }
    'skip$
      if$
      s nameptr "{vv{ } }{ll{ }}{  f{ }}{  jj{ }}" format.name$ 't :=
      nameptr numnames = t "others" = and
    { "et al" * }
    { t sortify * }
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
}

FUNCTION {sort.format.title}
{ 't :=
  "A " #2
    "An " #3
      "The " #4 t chop.word
    chop.word
  chop.word
  sortify
  #1 global.max$ substring$
}

FUNCTION {author.sort}
{ author empty$
    { key empty$
    { "to sort, need author or key in " cite$ * warning$
      ""
    }
    { key sortify }
      if$
    }
    { author sort.format.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {author.editor.sort}
{ author empty$
    { editor empty$
    { key empty$
        { "to sort, need author, editor, or key in " cite$ * warning$
          ""
        }
        { key sortify }
      if$
    }
    { editor sort.format.names }
      if$
    }
    { author sort.format.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {author.organization.sort}
{ author empty$
    { organization empty$
    { key empty$
        { "to sort, need author, organization, or key in " cite$ * warning$
          ""
        }
        { key sortify }
      if$
    }
    { "The " #4 organization chop.word sortify }
      if$
    }
    { author sort.format.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {editor.organization.sort}
{ editor empty$
    { organization empty$
    { key empty$
        { "to sort, need editor, organization, or key in " cite$ * warning$
          ""
        }
        { key sortify }
      if$
    }
    { "The " #4 organization chop.word sortify }
      if$
    }
    { editor sort.format.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {presort}
{ type$ "book" =
  type$ "inbook" =
  or
    'author.editor.sort
    { type$ "proceedings" =
    'editor.organization.sort
    { type$ "manual" =
        'author.organization.sort
        'author.sort
      if$
    }
      if$
    }
  if$
  "    "
  *
  year field.or.null sortify
  *
  "    "
  *
  title field.or.null
  sort.format.title
  *
  #1 entry.max$ substring$
  'sort.key$ :=
}

ITERATE {presort}

SORT

STRINGS { longest.label }

INTEGERS { number.label longest.label.width }

FUNCTION {initialize.longest.label}
{ "" 'longest.label :=
  #1 'number.label :=
  #0 'longest.label.width :=
}

FUNCTION {longest.label.pass}
{ number.label int.to.str$ 'label :=
  number.label #1 + 'number.label :=
  label width$ longest.label.width >
    { label 'longest.label :=
      label width$ 'longest.label.width :=
    }
    'skip$
  if$
}

EXECUTE {initialize.longest.label}

ITERATE {longest.label.pass}

FUNCTION {begin.bib}
{ preamble$ empty$
    'skip$
    { preamble$ write$ newline$ }
  if$
  "\begin{thebibliography}{"  longest.label  * "}" * write$ newline$
}

EXECUTE {begin.bib}

EXECUTE {init.state.consts}

EXECUTE {init.last.authors}

ITERATE {call.type$}

FUNCTION {end.bib}
{ newline$
  "\end{thebibliography}" write$ newline$
}

EXECUTE {end.bib}
```

My output is
[image]

But I need this

[image]

`How to change the .bst functions to get the desired output?`

Comment: one of these may be helpful: [Make volume bold in custom bibliography style .bst](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82499/579), or [Bold journal volume number in formatted bibliographic item](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/281596/579)

Comment: @Alan Munn  I want to learn "How did you edit my `.bst` code to get in the above format". Every time I post the code, I use `four spaces` for each line of the code. The number of lines for `.tex` is less so I did it, but for `.bst` I left it as it would take a lot of time to do that.

Comment: @LitunJohn Instead of indenting each line yourself, just select the whole chunk of code an click on the `{}` icon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make the following changes to your `.bst` file:

Add the following function:

```
FUNCTION {bold}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    {pop$ "" }
    { "{\bfseries " swap$ * "}" * }
  if$
}
```

Then change the `format.vol.year` function to this:

```
FUNCTION {format.vol.year}
{ volume field.or.null
  year empty$
    { "empty year in " cite$ * warning$ }
    { bold " (" year * ")" *  *  }
  if$
}
```

Finally, change your `article` function to the following:

```
FUNCTION {article}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  format.title "title" output.check
  crossref missing$
    { journal "journal" new.block output.check
      " " * format.vol.year * 
    }
    { format.article.crossref  * }
  if$
  format.pages * 
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}
```

To remove the comma before "and" in multiple authors, change the following lines in the function `{format.names}`:

```
    { numnames #2 >
    { "," * }
```

to

```
    { numnames #2 >
    { " " * } % changed here
```

To add parentheses around dates we need to create a `{parens}` function, which is basically the same as the `{bold}` function I added above:

```
FUNCTION {parens}
 { duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    { "(" swap$ * ")" * }
   if$
}
```

Now we can put `parens` into the `{book}` function before we output the year.  I've changed this in the `{book}` function given below, but you will likely need to change it in other functions that have dates if your style is consistent.  Also, since you no longer need the comma before the parenthesized date, I've added `new.block` after the address output in this function also. You will need to do similarly for others.

```
FUNCTION {book}
{ output.bibitem
  author empty$
    { format.editors "author and editor" output.check }
    { format.authors output.nonnull
      crossref missing$
    { "author and editor" editor either.or.check }
    'skip$
      if$
    }
  if$
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  crossref missing$
    { format.bvolume output
      format.number.series output
      publisher "publisher" output.check
      address  output new.block
    }
    { format.book.crossref output.nonnull }
  if$
  format.edition output
  format.date parens "year" output.check
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}
```

[image: output of sample bib item]

Comment: Yes the modified code works for me to get a `bold` volume number. Still I need some more help in removing the `,` just before the `bold volume number`. Also, I want to replace the `,` by `.` at the end of the article title.

Comment: @LitunJohn I've updated the answer to make those changes (changed the `{article}` function.

Comment: In case of multiple authors, I got a `,` before `and last author`. How to remove that `,`.

Comment: @LitunJohn I've added that change in too. (But much of this could have been fixed with better choices when you used `makebst`...)

Comment: How to change the `year` in book format to `(year)`.

Comment: @LitunJohn I've added code showing you how to add parentheses. This is the last update I will make to this answer. By now you should be able to play around with the `.bst` file to get it to do what you want. If you play around and test things you should be able to figure the rest out.