# Help for Bibliography Style

Tags: biblatex, biber, bibliographystyle

I have to format the bibliography style according to my university requirements and need help.
It should look like this:

Burak Akgül, C., Rubin, D. L., Napel, S., Beaulieu, C. F., Greenspan, H., and Acar, B. (2011): Content-Based Image Retrieval in Radiology: Current Status and Future Directions. In:J. Digital Imaging **24.2**, pp. 208–222. doi:10.1007/s10278-010-9290-9. url:https://doi.org/10.1007/s10278-010-9290-9.

I currently have this:
Burak Akgül, C., Rubin, D. L., Napel, S., Beaulieu, C. F., Greenspan, H., and Acar, B. “Content-Based Image Retrieval in Radiology: Current Status and Future Directions”. In:J. Digital Imaging24.2 (2011), pp. 208–222. doi:10.1007/s10278-010-9290-9. url:https://doi.org/10.1007/s10278-010-9290-9.

I am using this for formation:

```
\usepackage[bibstyle=numeric,citestyle=authoryear,maxbibnames=99,uniquelist=false,maxcitenames=1,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{main-reference.bib}
\DeclareNameAlias{author}{last-first}
...
\printbibliography
```

The references should be numbered and I use \cite{}.
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Is it not a specific style (APA, MLA, etc.)? If you have that information you might be able to figure out how to ask Biblatex to use that style.

Comment: how do you cite? it will be interesting which style it is

Comment: I use \cite{} for citing

Comment: This question already have an answer. Pl. check: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286680/how-to-edit-a-bst-file-to-get-bold-volume-number-in-case-of-articles

Comment: @MS Technically, it has not, at least not under the link you provide. There, the answer refers to `bibtex` and how to modify a .bst-file, while this question here wants to achieve the same using `biblatex`.

Comment: My Bad. Didn't check the `biblatex` part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with some modifications, which you should all include after loading `biblatex` and before `\begin{document}`

You want to get rid of the quotation marks around the title. Use

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]{title}{#1\isdot}
```

You can modify the list in brackets if you just want to remove quotation marks for some entry types but not all, or leave away the brackets entirely to have no quotation marks around titles at all.

You want the volume and issue in bold in journals. Use

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\textbf{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{issue}{\textbf{#1}}
```

That's all I see at the moment. Does it now look as you want it?

Comment: It almost looks like it should be, thank you very much. I still need the year after the authors and before : title

Comment: The format should be author (year) : title

Comment: @Laura If the bibliography should follow an author-year layout, then something like https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/314014/35864 might help.